# Regex works in Browser but not in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

On a browser this

```
"C:\\backup\\".replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')
```

returns:

```
"C:\backup\"
```

BUT in NodeJs v12.13

```
'C:\\backup\\'
```

Is it intended to not work the similar way?
If so, how to replace all double backslash to a single one in Node ?

Comment: `"C:\backup\"` is not even a valid JS string. I think you are confused about escaping. In JS `\\` means `\`, no need to replace.

Comment: in Firefox it's also returning `"C:\\backup\\"`

Comment: It works totally fine! you can see it here https://i.imgur.com/LaQqwOu.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript string a **single backslash** is represented using `"\\"`. That's because `\"` represents a single `"` character and doesn't terminate the string.

The regex you wrote actually has *no effect* because the string doesn't contain two backslashes next to one another.

You can (and should) use `\\` in any place/function that expects a backslash.

```js
alert("Backslash: \\");
// alert("Backslash: \"); // SyntaxError
```

However, the JavaScript console *sometimes* likes to display the sting in JavaScript notation, so it replaces `\` with `\\` in order to print valid code. This also *sometimes* happens when typing just a string in the console REPL.

```js
console.log("%o", "\\");
console.log({ backslash: "\\"});
```

Notice the "*sometimes*". Per [spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer), the JavaScript console printer is implementation-defined. Although most consoles, including Node.js's, in these circumstances display `"\\"` (a valid JavaScript string), Chrome and other Chromium-based browsers display `"\"` (the actual string value, wrapped in `"`).

---

P.S.: There's also a way to make the parser parse a single backslash as a single backslash, using `String.raw()`, however, it has some limitations:

```js
alert(String.raw `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe`);
// alert(String.raw `C:\Windows\System32\`); // SyntaxError because string ends with \
```

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question. why is there a difference between the way it's interpreted in Chrome vs. Node or Firefox?

Comment: The difference comes from *how* the string it is used. For example, if `"\\"` is typed in the REPL or used in the console like in my answer, it will print `"\\"` or `'\\'`. However, if it is used in other ways (e.g. accessing a file or printing to STDOUT), it will be interpreted as ``\``.

Comment: Chrome's console behaves differently from Firefox's console

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that (I was using Firefox and assumed it was the same thing.